# COPY command Redshift | Integer column with csv data

Tags: csv, integer, copy, command, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to do a copy command to Redshift Table using s3 data in csv format. However i'm getting this error :

`ERROR:Invalid digit, Value 'a', Pos 0, Type: Long`

The Redshift table that I'm trying to do the COPY is with a specific column that is in BIGINT. But I can't specify in the COPY command the type integer.

Here's the query:

```
`COPY "database"."schema"."table" (col1, col2, 
 col3, col4, col5, col6)
 FROM 's3-path'
 iam_role 'arn-role-with-command-access-role-policy'
 csv;`
```

I want to do the query stablishing "col1" as BIGINT in the COPY.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the csv header were added to the COPY, and "col1" is a string trying to be added in a BIGINT column. So I had to put in the COPY command IGNOREHEADER 1 in order to skip the first row in csv file.

That solve my problem.